# GTK3+ Getting Segmentation Fault when using gtk_window_get_title

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm currently creating a GUI that has buttons to delete and create a grid each time to simulate going to the next or previous page. The first time I go to the next page it works fine and returns me the string of the window's title.

However, once I attempt to go back to the previous page,

`char *titles = gtk_window_get_title(GTK_WINDOW(window))`

prints out (null) and a segmentation fault occurs. I have also tried changing the title to `static` but to no avail.

I am using
`if (strcmp(titles, PgOne) == 0)` to check which page the user is currently on so the program knows the subsequent page to create.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

char *PgTwo = "Page 2";
char *PgOne = "Page 1";

static void NewCallback(GtkWidget *grid, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *gridNew;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;

    gridNew = gtk_grid_new();
    window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel(grid);
    gtk_widget_destroy(grid);

    char *titles = gtk_window_get_title(GTK_WINDOW(window));

    if (strcmp(titles, PgTwo) == 0)
    {
        gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Page 1");
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), gridNew);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Next Page");
        g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(NewCallback), grid);
        /* Place the button in the grid cell (0, 1), and make it fill Span 2 columns */
        gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
        g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), window);
        /* Place the Quit button in the grid cell (0, 2), and make it Span 2 columns. */
        gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 2, 2, 1);
    }
    else if (strcmp(titles, PgOne) == 0)
    {
        gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Page 2");
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), gridNew);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Back to Main Menu");
        g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(NewCallback), grid);
        /* Place the Quit button in the grid cell (0, 2), and make it Span 2 columns. */
        gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(gridNew), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);
    }

    // Recursive show all items in window
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *button;

    /* create a new window, and set its title */
    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Page 1");
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 100);

    /* Here we construct the container that is going pack our buttons */
    grid = gtk_grid_new();

    /* Pack the container in the window */
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), grid);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Next Page");
    g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(NewCallback), grid);
    /* Place the button in the grid cell (0, 1), and make it fill Span 2 columns */
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
    g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), window);
    /* Place the Quit button in the grid cell (0, 2), and make it Span 2 columns. */
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 2, 2, 1);

    // Recursive show all items in window
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

// Main function is here
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

Comment: You probably provide some invalid pointer for `window`. As you hide all your code, how would we know? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Apologies, have edited my question to include a MCVE @Gerhardh

Comment: Probably not the reason for your issue, but why are you swapping parameters for callbacks? That might be useful for using library functions missing first parameter, but for your own callbacks I can't see any reason.

Comment: Where do you get the `nul` printout? Is `window` `NULL` or is `title` `NULL`? And how is this printed? Some assertion from GTK?

Comment: You mixed up your variables: `gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);` You already destroyes `grid`. This should be `grid_new` instead.

Comment: Yes that's the solution I just came to as well. Thank you. I was looking through my code again and realised under both ```gtk_grid_attach``` and ```g_signal_connect_swapped``` were grid. Replaced them with gridNew and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the variable `grid` to `gridNew` as I have already called `gtk_widget_destroy(grid)` prior.

```
g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(NewCallback), gridNew);
```

Tried to accept my solution but tells me to wait 2 days before accepting it